# Mocking cursor.fetchone() returns None istead of returning a value in python

Tags: python, mocking, pyodbc, python-unittest, magicmock

I wrote a function for my project which fetches data from MSSQL server using Pyodbc. The function works fine. When I write unittest cases using unittest and mock library and mocked the cursor.fetchone and returned a predefined value but while running the test case it returns None instead of returning the value.
Here are my code.

Store.py

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="source_monitor.log", format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='a') 
logger=logging.getLogger() 


class KMExtracter:
    def __init__(self,metric_collected_date):
        self.metric_collected_date = metric_collected_date
    # argument conn is a db connection which will passed in seperate program
    def get_metrics_by_technology(self, conn, technology):
        try:
        
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM URL_STORE WHERE Technology='{0}' firstExtractionDate  BETWEEN '{1} 00:00:00' AND '{1} 23:59:59'".format(self.technology[technology],
                        self.metric_collected_date
                ))
                
            
            count = cursor.fetchone()
            return count[0]
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("{0} at get_metrics_by_technology()".format(e))
```

test_store.py

```
class TestKM(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_metrics_by_technology(self):
        mock_data_interface = Mock()
        mock_data_interface.cursor.return_value.execute.return_value.fetchone.return_value(23987,)
        
        km = KMExtracter('2021-04-03')
        print(km.get_metrics_by_technology(mock_data_interface, 'SOME'))
        self.assertEqual(23987,km.get_metrics_by_technology(mock_data_interface, 'SOME'))
```

Error I got:
AssertionError: 23987 != None

Comment: The final return value must be a variable attribution not a call of a method. Ex: `fetchone.return_value = 23987`

Comment: Thank you @MauroBaraldi. Now it works I have changed the line from  mock_data_interface.cursor.return_value.execute.return_value.fetchone.return_value(23987,)  to mock_data_interface.cursor.return_value.fetchone.return_value(23987,)

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestKM(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_metrics_by_technology(self):
        mock_data_interface = Mock()
       
        # execute.return_value was removed from the below line.
        mock_data_interface.cursor.return_value.fetchone.return_value(23987,)
        
        km = KMExtracter('2021-04-03')
        print(km.get_metrics_by_technology(mock_data_interface, 'SOME'))
        self.assertEqual(23987,km.get_metrics_by_technology(mock_data_interface, 'SOME'))
```